# Is useMemo(()=>()=>{}, []) the same as useCallback(()=>{}, [])?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.  But for those who may have thought `useCallback` memoizes the result https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback states

> useCallback will return a memoized version of the **callback**

not the result.
nor build a callback that memoizes.

Anyway if `useMemo(()=>()=>{...}, [])` was mean to workaround a misunderstanding of the `useCallback` functionality would it be the same as `useCallback(()=>{}, [])` ?

Comment: As it says _in what you've linked to_, _"`useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) says they are the same:

> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps).

Another thing to keep in mind for both `useMemo` and `useCallback` is [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a
> semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some
> previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g.
> to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it
> still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.

Comment: DOH. Thx. Must be getting tired that I missed that a few lines down.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Yes, seems you missed that.